# How can I remove a feature's edge without hitting 'Del'

Tags: qgis, editing

We use tablet PC with windows 10 and QGIS installed.
We need to modify polygon and polyline features and we need to delete some edges. Normally, we use the 'Del' key of the keyboard but with the virtual keybord of win 10, this key is missing.

We have installed another virtual keyboard but this is not easy to use.
If possible, it would be great getting a button under QGIS  which removed selected edge.

This button exist under the topoedit toolbar but it works only with postgis layer.

Is there a Python script that could do the job?

Comment: Try in `Settings / Configure shortcuts`

Comment: I works with windows 10 and qgis 2.18. I want to simplify some polygons by deleting some edge.

Comment: Thank you AndreJ, this need activate the virtual keyboard and it hide a large part of qgis. The best way will be a specific button. I'm going to search in the python library if i find something

Answer (score 1):

If your virtual keyboard does not have a `Del` key, you can use the `Backspace`
key as well to delete a selected vertex.

Maybe related: http://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/ There seems to be a `Keyboard` key in the lower right corner that changes the keyboard layout.